# why the String doesnt converrt to JsonArray

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley

I'm coding for an Android app and running it on mobile
(Pie version) And I use the Volley library to connect to the server.
When I send a request to the server (JsonArrayRequest) the application logs 
onErrorRespons
And it faces this error

```
com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <html> 
<body> <script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Here is an example of server and Android code
I even used this code on the server
    header ('Content-Type: application/json');
 but I still got the same error

You can use this link to view the content http://alibaba.gigfa.com/getcity.php

Thank you for your efforts, friends

php:

```
<?php
 include "connect.php";
 $query="SELECT * FROM city";
 $res=$connect->prepare($query);
 $res->execute();
 $products=array();
 while($row=$res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     $record=array();
     $record["id"]=$row["id"];
     $record["title"]=$row["city"];

     $products[]=$record;
 }
 echo json_encode($products);

 ?>
```

java:

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new 
 JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new 
 Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
             public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.e("Adrom Response1: ", response.toString());
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        String city = jsonObject.getString("title");
                        cities.add(city);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("Adrom Response2: ", e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

        }


        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Adrom Response3: ", error.toString());
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

Comment: What is the exact json that you’re trying to send to the endpoint?

Comment: It's extremely clear: The string you have starts with `<html>`. You're getting an HTML reply; see what is inside it. It may be an error message, or you might need to specify an `Accept` header. (Also note that most Java REST libraries will automatically unwrap a real Java object for you like `City` instead of making you deal with `JSON*` yourself.)

Comment: You can use this link to view the content
http://alibaba.gigfa.com/getcity.php